# Excluding a function or entire file from code coverage count in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, unit-testing, code-coverage

Is it possible to exclude an entire file or certain functions from being counted towards code coverage? For example some stuff cannot be tested. Is there a way to tell Xcode that coverage is still 100% if you don't test something and how to exclude it or where?